# How to exclude Brand Category Path from Product URL but keep Brand Name included?

Tags: url

I want to get rid of the "Brands" and "Brand Name" in the following Product URL:

`http://example.com/brands/brand-name/Ladies-jeans-5464.html`

But I need the Product URL to include the "Brand Name" and always look like this (regardless of the path that is used to get to the Product Page):

`http://example.com/brand-name-Ladies-jeans-5464.html`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to (easily) achieve this is:

1. Go to `System > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engines Optimization` and set "Use Web Server Rewrites" to Yes. This will remove the Category Path from the product URL.

and

2. Make sure to use the Brand Name in the product URL.